# Typescript & MongoDB type erasing when adding methods to the schema

Tags: mongodb, typescript

I've been playing around with typescript and mongodb for the past few days and I wanted to add a custom method which I can execute on `Document` instances. Here is my setup:

```js
import { Document, Schema, model, Model } from "mongoose";
import { AlbumSchema, AlbumDocument } from './album';
```

And here is my Document interface:

```js
interface ArtistDocument extends Document {
    name: string;
    identifier: string;
    albums: [AlbumDocument];

    testFunction(): string
}
```

And my Schema:

```js
const ArtistSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    identifier: {type: String, required: true},
    albums: {type: [AlbumSchema], required: true, default: []}
});

ArtistSchema.methods.testFunction = function(): string {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Note that I can just call `testFunction();` on an instance of `Artist` just fine. So I know that methods are working.

Here is the issue though:

```js
ArtistSchema.methods.testFunction = function(): string {
    return "Albums:" + this.albums.length;
}
```

`this.albums` (which should be of type `AlbumDocument[]`) is somehow type `any` and therefore I can not use any array builtin functions nor can I filter and have `AlbumDocument` available to use its properties.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong? Is there a fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to instanciate albums like so :

```
albums:new Array<AlbumDocument>();
```